# Is there a difference in the time taken to load one texture instead of many?

Tags: unity, textures, performance, optimization

Is there a difference in the loading time of 16 256*256 textures versus a single 1024*1024 texture? Specifically for level loading time?

Comment: Why did you delete this question? It's valid (although the part about runtime performance is a duplicate).

Comment: Also "try it and see" is not a valid or constructive comment, so I've removed the relevant discussion. Be nice, folks.

Comment: "Try and see" is valid to some questions or problems. It could be helpful for the OP to learn more about the topic and get a clearer understanding of what they're asking. Probably not the case for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In theory*, loading many textures will be slower. In practice, the actual amount by which it is "slower" is probably negligible.

There are two main bottlenecks:

- Reading the texture file off the disk.
- Sending the texture to the GPU.

Files on disk have some small-but-non-zero overhead in terms of book-keeping information for the filesystem. Thus, 16 files storing otherwise the same data as one may be slightly larger than the single file alone. Further, files are disk are typically actually allocated at some multiple of a disk's sector size, which can exacerbate that difference slightly (given the size of typical textures these days, however, it's not really a concern until you start getting into the hundreds or thousands of texture files).

However, multiple files aren't necessarily located at the same spot on the disk. While less of a concern for SSDs, spinning-disk hard drives (and disc drives) are still commonly in use for games. To read a file off of such a drive, the read head must physically move (or the disk must move underneath it) to the appropriate location, which introduces seek time into the load operation.

Games that ship on disc media (like console games) used to aggressively arrange the physical layout of their files on the media to optimize for seek times. It's still done occasionally. These disk IO overheads are also one of the reasons why many games pack all their "files" into a single monolithic archive: to amortize the cost, in physical storage and OS overhead, of reading a file across the entire file set instead of paying it for every tiny file.

Similarly, you will have some setup and transmission overhead in sending the texture data to the GPU for use. So if you can pack things into a single / fewer textures, it will generally save you those costs (as well as the overhead of the state switch), so it's preferable if it makes sense and does not result in other compromises for performance (there is a point at which shoving everything into a single texture may save you the file IO performance hit, but cost you *more* in some performance hit elsewhere; you'll have to find that balance).

Many of these issues won't be *serious* unless you are dealing with a high volume of files and constantly hitting the disk or the GPU bus to move them about. You can also hide a lot of the problems behind multithreaded design, if you can do something else during the IO that eliminates the IO from the critical path.

But generally, if there is an overhead for some operation that you will perform *N* times, and that overhead can be paid *once* instead of *N* times, it's generally better to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know nothing about your level loading, but generally processing more of smaller objects (textures in your case) is a bit slower than processing just one. But processing a huge one is troublesome too.

Think of it as transporting a pile of stones from A to B. If you carry each gravel piece one by one you will loose a lot of time and effort on walking here and there almost empty-handidly. On the other side, if you decide to transport the whole pile at once you likely to be limited by amount of weight you can lift.

TL;DR. There's an optimal size and count. You need to test that for yourself, considering your target hardware.